# Display Inline Creating Space Below

Tags: html, css

Can anybody help me out with a little CSS issue? I know CSS, however I'm pretty bad at debugging it. I'm not sure when I give both my Academic Information and Personal Information `display: inline-block` why there is several lines of white space appended to the bottom (above "Tell Us More About You").

I'm assuming this is the space that Personal Information would take up if it was not on the same line as Academic Information.

**I would like for the space above "Tell Us More About You" to be gone and have both top section and bottom section up against each other.**

HTML (don't tell me about how inline styling is bad (I know)):

```
<html>
 <head>
    <title>test</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div style="display: inline-block;"><a style="font-size: 16pt;">ASAP APPLICATION   FORM</a><img style="margin-left: 400px; height: 35px;" src="../css/images/asap_logo.png">  </div>
    <hr>

    <div>Date Submitted: <b><?php echo $_GET['dateSubmitted'] ?></b><br></div><br>

    <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <h3><i>ACADEMIC INFORMATION</i></h3>
        <div>
            Major:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['major'] ?></u></b>
            <div style="margin-top: 8px;">Expected Graduation Year:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['gradDate'] ?></u></b></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 8px;">Relevant work?:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo ucfirst($_GET['work']) ?></u></b></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div style="display: inline-block; margin-left: -300px;">
        <h3><i>PERSONAL INFORMATION</i></h3>
        <div>
            Name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['firstName']." ".$_GET['lastName'] ?></u></b><br>
            <div style="margin-top: 8px;">Address:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['address'] ?></u></b><br></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 8px;">Phone:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['phone'] ?></u></b><br></div>
            <div style="margin-top: 8px;">Email:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><u><?php echo $_GET['email'] ?></u></b></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <h3><i>TELL US MORE ABOUT YOU</i></h3>
    <b>Position(s) interested in:</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo $_GET['positions'] ?>
    <br>
    <b>Do you have work-study?</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo ucfirst($_GET['workStudy']) ?>
    <br>

    <span>Describe your creative strengths:</span>
    <textarea><?php echo $_GET['previousExperience'] ?></textarea>

    <span>Briefly describe your previous work experience:</span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $_GET['creativeStrengths'] ?></textarea>

    <span>What are your skills?:</span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $_GET['skills'] ?></textarea>

    <span>What interests you about this position?:</span>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="40"><?php echo $_GET['interests'] ?></textarea>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Picture (this is converted to a PDF by the way):

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle with this code?

Comment: Using `&nbsp;` for spacing is really bad practice. I don't really know why you're using `margin-left: -300px` either. My first suggestion would be to brush up on CSS - take an online tutorial, perhaps.

Comment: Because it appears outside the PDF, and thanks, but I know how to use CSS.

Comment: @Nicolas oh I see, I missed that part in your question. Based on what you've provided I cannot say why that gap is there. Copying and pasting this entire block of code into a new HTML document doesn't reproduce the same problem.

Comment: Yeah it looks different as HTML. The picture posted is the HTML converted to a PDF.

Comment: If it looks fine as HTML, the problem can lie in the conversion to PDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a div with the same display:inline-block around the bottom section as well.

Comment: It kind of works. Except the "Tell Us More About You" title is touching the "Email" field. I'm unable to push it down at all.

Comment: Well, as others have said this still isn't the best practice, but you can always add 'padding-top:10px;'

Comment: Works! One last bug is that my textareas now extend outside the pdf.. I tried giving them a set width but they won't resize.

Comment: Try lowering the cols count, it will override the width.

Comment: I removed the rows and cols attribute but it still extends past.

Comment: You removed cols and kept width on them? or just removed cols? You can also add a width to the body. How are you rendering this to PDF exactly?

Comment: Got it! Thanks. May not be the nicest, but it works.